# MySQL 18 queries required, or can I use just one?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a golf score tracking database for some friends and am having trouble with the best way to retrieve a specific value from the result.

I have tables:

```
Players - stores player info
Hole - stores basic info about a hole (CourseID, HoleNum, Par...)
Score - stores each hole they played (HoleID, NumStrokes...)
```

My goal is to output a table showing their result for each hole (1-18). The following query gets me a list of all of the holes they played and the number of strokes it took them to complete the hole.

```
SELECT Hole.HoleID, NumStrokes
FROM Players
INNER JOIN Score ON Score.PlayerID = Players.PlayerID
INNER JOIN Hole ON Score.HoleID = Hole.HoleID
WHERE Players.PlayerID = '$PlayerID'
```

Results like this:

```
HoleID      NumStrokes
1           4
1           6
1           3
2           5
7           3
```

Do I have to run 18 different queries, one for each hole that I am outputting, by adding:

```
AND Hole.HoleID = '$HoleID'
```

to my query, or is there a better SQL query that I could use? The Hole table also as a round identifier, so don't worry about determinig which NumStrokes of HoleID I need. I'm using PHP, by the way. Hopefully my question was clear enough.

Thank you!

Comment: why would you need to run it 18 times, can't you just get the result from the first query with all the holes?

Comment: That's what I'm wondering. I might be going brain dead, but how would I grab the value in NumStrokes for the HoleID of 2, without adding that criteria I listed below the query? And, if I added the criteria listed below the original query, I'd need to change the $HoleID for each of the 18 holes, resulting in 18 loops of the query.

Comment: So, if I'm correct your question isn't really how to get the `NumStrokes` for each `HoleID` in one query, because your initial query does a fine job at retrieving those, but the real question is: "How do I cycle through these resulting records in PHP", correct?

Comment: Yeah, doesn't that query get you already all the holes you need? Assuming a hole can only have a score if it was "played" by a player, it's just a matter of filtering the results you are getting from the first query, a job for PHP.

Comment: I guess what I'm getting at is, is the only way to get a set of results and display it to narrow down your results to one record, using the added criteria I listed above. If that's true, it turns into just another regular query that I'd put into an array in PHP and use `$row['NumStrokes']` to grab the value. Is that the most efficient way to do it...looping the query 18 times, one for each possible hole played? And to @Remco Overdijk, does "cycling through the results" mean using a while loop of my initial query?

Comment: the most efficient to get results for a given hole is using `AND Hole.HoleID = '$HoleID'`, the most efficient way to get the results for all of them will be to get all of them with one query (without the AND..).

Comment: @Vatev Sorry if I'm misunderstanding, but when you say "all of them" does that mean it is possible to get "all holes played" for that user at a course in a single, non-looping, query? If so, how would I do that? I know the syntax to get it in a query `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)`, but I'm struggling figuring out how to get the scores for holes 1-18 on a single array, since they are not stored in the same record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$conn = new mysqli('host','user','pass','db_name');

$PlayerID = (int) $_GET['PlayerID'];

$rs = $conn->query("
    SELECT Hole.HoleID, NumStrokes
    FROM Players
    INNER JOIN Score ON Score.PlayerID = Players.PlayerID
    INNER JOIN Hole ON Score.HoleID = Hole.HoleID
    WHERE Players.PlayerID = $PlayerID
") or die($conn->error);
while($row = $rs->fetch_object()) {
    echo $row->HoleID.' - '.$row->NumStrokes.'<br/>';
}
```

This will output the results for a player. You can do the same with the mysql_* functions, but since they are deprecated its better to use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Thank you, and thanks for the nudge to move to MYSQLi...I've just been lazy and not wanting to update everything :)